# How do I order lines to be correct?

Tags: python, if-statement

question is to arrange lines in order and with correct indent. I can't write anything just need to arrange it. question is in the picture. what's wrong with my answer[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fVzW.png)

Comment: What is wrong with your answer?   I think the last three print lines need to move left, outside the 'else'

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in range(1,6):
    if i == 1:
        print(i, 'little bear')
    else:
        print(i, 'little bears')
    print('Wondering what to do')
    print('Along came another')
    print('Then there were', i+1, '!')
```

Comment: i just can say thanks for your help.it worked.

Comment: You're welcome.  Accept the correct answer and upvote it when the site allow you to.   Good luck with Python.

Comment: Up arrow?  Vote it up?  Can you do that as a new user?

Comment: No I can't. I accepted answer but I can't upvote it

Comment: No worries.   Good luck.